# sp_generate_inserts for all the tables? or something similar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases.
Database A - full of data
Database B - backup of database A, but without data

how can I get all data from database A and just merge it into database B?
My thoughts were to just generate an insert of the whole data or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [redgate's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Answer (score 1):

OP said:

> database is full of triggers and
>   constraints

**Just restore a complete backup of A as a new database and be done with it.**  Lots of "one off" inserts created by a script will take forever, play havoc with your transaction log, and most likely fail because of FKs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That would work if you're trying to do something ongoing, but if you want to do it just once and you have SQL Server Management Studio installed, you can have it do the Export/Import for you. Here's a walk-though with some screenshots:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any identity fields to worry about, and it's a one-time operation, you can do something like this, which uses `sp_msforeachtable` and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = '
INSERT INTO DatabaseB.? WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseA.?'

exec sp_MSforeachtable @SQL
```

Comment: The database is full of triggers and constraints, does that influence the result?

Comment: @John - definitely, it won't work if you have FK constraints unless you get lucky and the constraints all work in alphabetical order of precedence, like you need to populate `AA` before `BB` which is before `CC`.  Otherwise you'll hit a constraint error.